# Traversing a json to remove nulls fields using jq

Tags: json, elasticsearch, null, jq

I have a JSON as follows but need a way to remove nulls before putting it into elasticsearch. Looking for a simple jq command to remove nulls that i can incorporate into my bash script unless there's a way to do this in elasticsearch

```
{
    "master_no": {
      "master_no": 100000000,
      "barcode": "E00000000",
      "external_key": null,
      "umid": null
    },
    "cust_id": {
      "other_cust_id": null,
      "cust_reference": null,
      "external_key": null,
      "list_id": null,
      "cust_id": null
    },
    "customer_name": null,
    "master_desc": "test Custom Patch - test",
    "barcode": "E00000000",
    "container_master_no": null,
    "master_status": "I",
    "length": "0:00",
    "format_no": {
      "format_desc": null,
      "external_key": null,
      "format_no": null
    },
    "lib_master_audio": [
      {
        "master_no": 10000000,
        "audio_channel_no": {
          "audio_channel_no": 10,
          "audio_channel": "1",
          "external_key": null
        }
      },
      {
        "master_no": 100000000,
        "audio_channel_no": {
          "audio_channel_no": 10,
          "audio_channel": "2",
          "external_key": null
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This GitHub issue on [remove null key and values from JSON](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/104) can help you, in short, some handful of command might help you like, mentioned in [this](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/104#issuecomment-167396874) link :

```
del(.[][] | nulls)
```

Please note there are several methods of doing this, please check which one works for you.

**As pointed out in comments by @oguz, Please use** https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/104#issuecomment-289637207 which work with the latest version.

Comment: @oguzismail, thanks for pointing this, I will edit this in my answer